# How to get rid of AVG Watchdog & AGVAmps services Win 7

Tags: windows-7, services, kill, avg-antivirus

First time poster here so please be kind!

Been having a few problems with my mouse the last couple days & while investigating the problem I happened on these two services in my task manager...

"AVG Watchdog" - reports running

"AVGAmps" - reports stopped

Did a bit of reading on what they were but cannot find a way to get rid of them.
I understand what they do & why cmd access to them is denied but here's the thing... I uninstalled AVG months ago because it was spending all my computers resources forcing unwanted sales pitches down my throat every 5 minutes.

I want nothing to do with AVG or their bloatware and have voted with my feet, yet still their cr@p remains on my system taking up resources and no doubt harvesting data.

Please, someone - short of an f-disk how do I get rid of this garbage for good?
I'm comfortable dipping into the registry if needs be but would need to know what to look for & how to manipulate it when I find it. Would of course prefer a simpler solution if one exists but I'll take anything you got!

Many thanks in advance

Stig

Comment: AVG offers a tool to remove their products.  I suggest use by that.

Comment: @Ramhound... I'll be damned - that actually worked! Thankyou! Did not know such a tool existed, as it hadn't showed up in any of my searches. Have to admit I was reluctant to use another AVG tool ever again but since it didn't need to install anything and has actually done the job - well it's all good! Very many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I want nothing to do with AVG or their bloatware

I suggest just using the [AVG Remover](https://www.avg.com/en-us/utilities) to remove any trace of the AVG software in question.